# Style a part of widget title for Blogger?

Tags: css, widget, title, blogger

How do I make only one "word2" of the widget title bold or of red color?

Or how do I split Blogspot widget title in two or three inline parts? And then separately style its parts.

in CSS I got:

```
<b:widget id='Profile1' locked='false' title='word1 word2 word3' type='Profile' version='1' visible='true'>
```

All my multiple attempts produced errors, coz I am not a PRO

Answer (score 1):

Blogger only allows adding the following HTML tags in the Title field of a widget -

> You can use some HTML tags, such as **`<b>`**, **`<i>`**, **`<a>`**

In your case, when editing the title of your widget, change it to -

```
word1 <b>word2</b> word3
```

Changing the color and other properties cannot be directly done. You will instead need to use the above HTML tags and CSS to achieve that

Like for example -

1. You want `word2` to be bold and with red color, then you will first need to modify the title to

   ```
   word1 <b>word2</b> word3
   ```

   and then also add the following CSS

   ```
   #Profile1 h2 b {color:red;}
   ```
2. If you only want the `word2` to have the color red, without being bold, then modify the title to

   ```
   word1 <b>word2</b> word3
   ```

   and then add the following CSS

   ```
   #Profile1 h2 b {color:red;font-weight:normal;}
   ```
3. If you want the `word1` to have bold font & color blue and the `word3` to have the color green,  then modify the title to

   ```
   <b>word1</b> word2 <b>word3</b>
   ```

   and then add the following CSS

   ```
   #Profile1 h2 b:nth-child(1) {color:blue;}
   #Profile1 h2 b:nth-child(2) {color:green;font-weight:normal;}
   ```

The CSS selector will change according to the `id` of the widget.